# FileNotFoundException occured when I did Spring Test with @Sql

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, gradle, junit, spring-test

I lean Spring Boot with Book.(copy and paste from book to editor)

There is I can't understand and not working code.

Could you teach me How can I fix and what should I learn?

```
@Test
//@Sql("file:C:/Users/<username>/Desktop/springsample/src/test/resources/testdata.sql") //This is work!
@Sql("/testdata.sql") // This is not work.
public void countTest2(){
    assertEquals(dao.count(), 3);
}
```

Please check above code, `@Sql("/testdata.sql")` is not work.

Junit result is like that.

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [testdata.sql] cannot be opened because it does not exist

So I wrote code that is comment out now. It worked.

I think that have to rewrite @Sql argument. But I don't know how to do that.

Could you teach me how to rewrite code?

Is this problem come from lack of my Maven directory rule?

**Appendix**

Directory tree is below.

```
tree /F C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\springsample\src\test
C:\USERS\<username>\DESKTOP\SPRINGSAMPLE\SRC\TEST
├─java
│  └─com
│      └─example
│          └─springsample
│                  DemoApplicationTests.java
│                  UserDaoTest.java //Test code in this file.
│
└─resources
        testdata.sql
```

Thank you for reading.

**Additional Info**

I read reference,then tried below setting is work.
In this case, need to put the .sql file same directory as Test class file.
I think can assignment specified location. But I can't.

```
@Sql("testdata.sql")
```

■Directory Tree

```
C:\USERS\<username>\DESKTOP\SPRINGSAMPLE\SRC\TEST
├─java
│  └─com
│      └─example
│          └─springsample
│                  DemoApplicationTests.java
│                  UserDaoTest.java //Test code in this file.
│                  testdata.sql
└─resources
  └─com
      └─example
          └─springsample
```

Answer (score 2):

@Sql by default looks for the files in the package of the @Test class.

for you case it should be as below

```
C:\USERS\<username>\DESKTOP\SPRINGSAMPLE\SRC\TEST
├─java
│  └─com
│      └─example
│          └─springsample
│                  DemoApplicationTests.java
│                  UserDaoTest.java //Test code in this file.
│
└─resources
│  └─com
│      └─example
│          └─springsample
│                  testdata.sql
```

Comment: Thank you for reply.
I made directory , and move .sql file there that you taught me.
But FileNotFoundException is still occured by same reason.

Comment: remove the '/' in the front - its just @Sql("testdata.sql").    see https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/jdbc/Sql.html#scripts--

Comment: Thank you for reply and ginving information.
I removed '/' , and ran test but same result....
I searched other article and information. According to that same you tought me.
So,I don't know why my code dosen't work.